# Cache memory logic

Tags: cpu-architecture

A computer has 1MB RAM and has a word size of 8 bits. Its has cache memory having 16 blocks with a block size of 32 bits. Show how the main memory address 
1000 1111 1010 0101 1101 will be mapped to cache address, if

i) Direct cache mapping is used
ii) Associative cache mapping is used
iii)Two way Set associative cache mapping is used

Please enlighten me on how to solve this problem.I have looked all over and there is no detailed explanation on this.

Comment: https://people.freebsd.org/~lstewart/articles/cpumemory.pdf still pretty good explanation how it works

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux The OP is struggling with the basics of caches and you're suggesting to him to read Ulrich Drepper's 114-page article? I don't think that's a good advice.

Comment: You have to partition the memory address into three fields: an offset into a cache block, an index into the cache, and a tag that can be used to uniquely identify a cache block.

Comment: No one's helping

Comment: Need someone to help me on how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

32 bit is 4 bytes, you need 2 bits to address these 4 bytes (2^2) so you split off the 2 least significant bits from the address.

1000 1111 1010 0101 11-01

Direct mapped means it can go only into one place in the cache, there are 16 places in the cache so we must peel off the next least 4 bits (2^4=16) getting

1000 1111 1010 01-01 11-01

so 0111 (=7) is the line that gets filled.

If (Fully) Associative cache mapping is used it can go in any of the 16 positions.

Using two way Set associative cache mapping is alike direct mapped but where we split the cache in half (size=8=2^3), giving 2 possible position it can be stored in.

1000 1111 1010 010-1 11-01

so 111 is the index and any of the 2 possible positions can be used.

Read all about caches [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache).